# For what real values of $x$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{5^{n-1}}(x+2)^n $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> For what real values of $x$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{5^{n-1}}(x+2)^n$ converge?

My attempt: $-1< (x+2)^n < 1$. Now, $-3 < x < -1$, so by the Leibniz test,   the given series will converge in $-3 <x<-1$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

By ratio test

$$\left| \frac{(n+1)(x+2)^{n+1}}{5^{n}}\frac{5^{n-1}}{n(x+2)^n}\right|=\frac{n+1}{5n}\left|x+2\right|\to\frac{1}{5}\left|x+2\right|$$

then the series converges for $|x+2|<5 \implies -7<x<3$.

Then check separetely the cases $x=-7$ and $x=3$.

Comment: that mean  $x= - 7$  is the correct answer ...am i right ?

Comment: @Stupid Note that for $x=3 \implies \frac{n}{5^{n-1}}(x+2)^n=5n$ and for for $x=-7 \implies \frac{n}{5^{n-1}}(x+2)^n=5n(-1)^n$.

Comment: thanks @gimusi  i got its

Comment: @Stupid Well done! You are welcome, Bye